# Overlay in jetty 9.2 or higher

Tags: eclipse, maven, jetty, jetty-9

I'm trying to use the jetty overlay as described at [official website](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/overlay-deployer.html). After a long research I've found this comment

> they made it into the repository but not the distro looks like

as described [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404508).

Following the link I've noticed that there is a lot of version of overlay available at [maven repository](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-overlay-deployer/).

My question is, where can I find a version of [jetty-overlay-deployer](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-overlay-deployer/) that is the same version of [current jetty version](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html). In other words, 9.3.10 or 9.3.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has not been an official release of this since 9.1. This was an feature that we never received a lot of feedback or use and was subsequently dropped from the build. I am opening the following bug to determine whether or not we are going to continue development or if we need to drop it from the documentation.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/843

If you have a use case for this feature, I would encourage you to open an issue on the GitHub repo as well so we can include it back as part of the official builds. The Maven repo you included is the most up to date jar for the feature.

Comment: Seconding the call to open an issue on github if you would like to see this come back, if we see a solid use case for it then we'll happily bring it back into the fold.

Comment: I'm going to explain tonigth with details about my use case. Thanks @Walkerwatch.

Comment: I have an interesting use case: We build a standard webapp wich is customized and installed in multiple clients. That customizations go from simple styles and text modifications to new libs and integrations added. We use build time overlays, which work great, but Jetty Runtime Overlays could be a really interesting alternative